# Google Maps directions in maps shared app to personalized annotations

Tags: ios, google-maps, annotations, mapkit, directions

I created an app that displays different points on a custom map with custom pins and showing the title and subtitle with a disclosure button (all right). The problem arises when the app launches maps to create the path and then provide directions. To move from the position of the user I've simply typed in the URL "saddr=Current Position". The problem comes when I try to give the destination that the user has touched, relative to the pin touched.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[UIViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
    NSString* addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%1.6f%1.6f&saddr=Posizione Attuale", mapView.annotations.coordinate.latitude mapView.annotations.coordinate.longitude];
```

//also mapview.annotation.coordinate.latitude/longitude doesn't work

```
        NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[addr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

I can not figure out how to pass the coordinates of the annotation in the piece of code!

Here's how I said and added the annotation to my view

```
    NSMutableArray* annotations=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate1;
    theCoordinate1.latitude = 45.7;
    theCoordinate1.longitude = 7.64;
myAnnotation* myAnnotation1=[[myAnnotation alloc] init];

    myAnnotation1.coordinate=theCoordinate1;
    myAnnotation1.title=@"Pippo";
    myAnnotation1.subtitle=@"Ufficio";
[myMapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation1];
```

This repeated for 4 main points that have different names (myAnnotation1, 2, 3, 4) and coordinates other! How can I do when the user touches 1-2-3 or 4 to move the right destination?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, why are you pushing a blank view controller and calling `openURL` at the same time?

Anyway, the annotation's coordinates are in `view.annotation.coordinate`.

So the latitude is `view.annotation.coordinate.latitude` and longitude is `view.annotation.coordinate.longitude`.

Also, in your `addr` string, you are missing a comma between the coordinates.

Comment: Thank You Anna, but if i put NSString* addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%1.6f%1.6f&saddr=Posizione Attuale", mapView.annotations.coordinate.latitude mapView.annotations.coordinate.longitude]; it doesn't work because "property coordinate not found". Same problem i can't find my latitude and longitude of my annotation

Comment: if I put exactly 'view.annotation.coordinate.latitude' and 'view.annotation.coordinate.longitude', xcode recognize them, but when i touch the disclusure button appear: "Thread 1 Stopped at breakpoint 5" whit the line green highlighted! :( In my project is correct call or I should adapt this code to my project?

Comment: Check if the URL object is coming out nil.  NSLog the addr string and the url variable.

Comment: Thank You Anna ! I've solved with:NSString* addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&saddr=Posizione attuale", view.annotation.coordinate.latitude,view.annotation.coordinate.longitude];